# bash: insert a line after a pattern using gawk

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I am trying to insert a line after the Pattern using `gawk`.
Let's say, file `aa` contains

```
11
22
33
11
22
33
```

I'm using gawk to insert 222 only after first 22, i.e. after insertion, my aa file would contain:

```
11
22
222
33
11
22
33
```

But, if I use:

```
 gawk -v nm=222 '/22/ {if (done++ == 0) print;print nm;next}1' aa
```

The file aa contains:

```
11
22
222
33
11
222
33
```

(I don't want second replacement of 22 by 222 and like to retain 22 as-is, and no more insertion, i,e,. insert 222 only once after first 22. 
Please help.

Comment: `gawk -v nm=222 '/22/ {if (done++ == 0){ print;print nm;next}}1'`

Comment: What about I would like to use 22 as a variable also? e.g. gawk -v nm1=22 -v nm2=222 '/nm1/ {if (done++ == 0){ print;print nm2;next}}1'

Comment: `$0~nm1{do stuff}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '1; $1==nm2 && !a++ {print nm1}' nm1=222 nm2=22 file
11
22
222
33
11
22
33
```

Explanation:

```
$ cat script.awk
1                    # print the line
$1==nm2 && !a++ {    # if $1 is exactly the desired and a counter hasn't been touched yet 
    print nm1        # print parameter nm2
}
```

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting.

Comment: I did not downvote. The code is correct, probably you should just add an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
awk '/^22$/ && !f {f=1; print; print "222"; next} 1' aa.txt
```

I'm checking if a line contains only a `22` and if the flag `f` is not set. In that case I set the flag to 1, print the current line and `222`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead:

```
gawk -v nm=222 '/22/ {if (done++ == 0){print;print nm;next}};1' aa
```

If the value 22 is in a variable: in `awk` you can not use `/constantRegex/`,
you need to use `~` :

```
sel=22
gawk -v nm=222 -v sel="$sel" '($0~sel) {if (done++ == 0){print;print nm;next}};1' aa
```

Comment: What about I would like to put 22 as a variable?