# bash: insert multiple lines after a line containing a pattern using gawk

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I had posted a question on [bash: insert a line after a pattern using gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744006/bash-insert-a-line-after-a-pattern-using-gawk.)

How do I insert more than one line after a line containing a pattern?

Comment: well, use the same solution but print the string containing those multiple lines or use multiple print statements...

Comment: I can't believe this absolutely minimal "question" has 2 answers already! Read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

String together your prints like `awk '<condition>{print $0; print "222"; print "223"; print "224"}`

Or use the newline character:

`awk '<condition>{print $0"\nthis is a line\nthis is a secondline\nthis is a thirdline"}`

Comment: or `awk 'BEGIN{print "line1" ORS "line2" ORS "line3"}'` ,if ORS is set to default.

Answer (score 1):

I modified `nm1` from 222 to `222\\n333` to add multiple lines at once (the command is from the answer of your original post )

```
awk '1; $1==nm2 && !a++ {print nm1}' nm1=222\\n333 nm2=22 file
```

output:

```
11
22
222
333
33
11
22
33
```